# View a PDF and TXT file from within an HTML static resource

Tags: static-resources, canvas, html5, iframe, object

So i have created a website in pure HTML 5, with some css's, jquery's and modals and locally on my PC it's all working great. I have some PDF and TXT files that i want to be able to view and it's working fine on HTML.

I zipped the whole site with all the folders and uploaded it as a static resource in Salesforce and the website is looking the same and the functionalities are working, except the viewing of the PDFs and TXTs.

I tried using an iframe, apex iframe, object, canvas and there's no way for me to view the pdfs and txt.

This is how i am calling it in my html:

```
<iframe src="pantallas/apex/cn_seguros.pdf" width="99.6%" height="800px" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

I read that iframes are no longer available in salesforce due to clickjacking but what other way is there to view these files from within the static resource where my html and pdfs are?[image]

I'm attaching an image of the static resource zip file i'm using
Should i maybe upload the PDF and TXT files in a separate static resource and reference the location of each file on the htmls on the other (main) static resource?

Comment: I've personally never done this but the way you are referencing the static resource in the source is wrong. You need to use the URLFOR to get the Salesforce URL for that resource unless it's somehow already loaded in previously.